# React-select: How to display HTML in options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-select

I am wondering if react-select could show html in rendered options. For example if fetched ajax option has `<b>text</b>`, I would like to see text as bold in the dropdown menu instead of seeing `<b>text</b>`.

I read the documentation and I didnt find any option for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I implemented the above solution and it broke the searchable feature. The label expects a string, not an element. -- There is actually a prop/function to do this

```
formatOptionLabel={function(data) {
  return (
    <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.label }} />
  );
}}
```

Check out this post: [React-Select: How to maintain search-ability while passing HTML to the label value in options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121386/react-select-how-to-maintain-search-ability-while-passing-html-to-the-label-val/63122700#63122700)

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
{ value: 'foo', label: <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'bar &amp; foo' }} /> }
```

No option component, no option renderer, just simple jsx.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution! However, this does seem to break `isSearchable`, do you have a work around for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the `optionComponent` prop of react-select and the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML feature](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) of React
And give to `optionComponent` a component like this

```
const MyOptionComponent = props => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html : props.option}} />;
```

Comment: hm I dont see how is this supposed to work;. `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`
also I am already using optionRenderer for a highlighter like in the example here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/5

Comment: use it like that: dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: finalHtml }}

Answer (score 1):

You can create either a custom `optionRenderer` or `optionComponent` for `react-select`.

I'd recommend you `optionRenderer` as it is more simple, if you only want to put convert to html. You can see an example here:

https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-taxonomypicker/blob/master/app/src/components/TaxonomyPicker/TaxonomyPicker.tsx#L135-L148

There is another example for `optionComponent` here (just in case you want extra functionality): 
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/CustomComponents.js#L15

Comment: Hi, you example is just changing the way the option is rendered, there is still a problem with html not being interpreted. I am already using custom optionRenderer for highlighter like explained here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/5